# Система контроля версий Mercurial. Номер ревизии из репозитория в проект

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mercurial

вопрос заключается в том, как в проект c# добавить информацию о ревизиях которые хранятся в личном репозитории Mercurial. Репозиторий хранится на отдельной машине доступной из интернет и локальной сети, в Visual Studio установлен плагин который позволяет пушить туда и т.п. Например я что то поменял в проекте, отправил в репозиторий, там появилась новая ревизия (rev. 1) - вот как мне этот номер автоматически запихивать к примеру в какой нибудь TextBox при сборке проекта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial - это просто система контроля исходников. За номером сборки должен следить билд сервер (например, [тимсити](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/AssemblyInfo+Patcher)) и этот билд сервер должен уметь патчить сборки нужной версией (тут вы и добавляете номера билдов, ревизий и тд), в соответствии с его настройками. А вы уже, после сборки билд сервером и запуска приложения, [получаете](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Client.Modules.MainModule/About.xaml.cs#L30) версию сборки и показываете её там, где хотите.